# Got all sorceries, but didn't win the Trophy

Tags: achievements, dark-souls

Here's some other information I can add:

- In this playthrough I used the [Bottomless Box trick](http://www.ps3trophies.com/forums/dark-souls/9159-amazing-bottomless-box-glitch-transfer-between-chars.html);
- I won the Pyromancies Trophy without having all pyromancies with this char.

I have all sorceries from this [list](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/sorceries).

I really don't want to play all the game again to get all those spells again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've been able to find, there's no record of the spell acquisition trophies being glitched in Dark Souls.  It may be a stupid comment, but are you absolutely sure that you have all the sorceries?  You've probably double- and triple-checked, but just in case.

My only other thought is that by using the BB glitch, you've glitched the trophy.  Googling the glitch doesn't turn anything up but I can see it being possible.  Did you use the glitch to acquire any of your sorceries?  If so, try re-acquiring those that you used the glitch to get.  Apart from that, I have no idea; it may be necessary to just bite the bullet and play through again with another character.

Comment: There's a similar trophy/BB glitch issue with the Knight's Honor trophy as well: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80692/i-cant-get-the-knights-honor-trophy. Might be related, caused by the same underlying code.