# I can't get the Knight's Honor trophy

Tags: achievements, dark-souls

Knight's Honor trophy will not come up. I've looked all over the net and I have all the weapons. Can someone give me the full list of what they are, please? I need to know if the trophy is glitched or not.  I got a list of all the weapons I need but it still did not come up.  Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: are the weapons all on one character?

Comment: yea it all on one

Comment: what about Shields

Comment: yea i have all i think . i need the full list to make sure

Comment: well if you go to the link it will tell you, Ill add it into the answer since you didn't click the link.

Comment: thank u i will see if have them or not i just wrort a it down

Comment: i have them all and the trophie will no pop up HELP

Comment: Please stop making low-quality edits to the question. The question is fine as it is.

Comment: Adding help into the title doesn't help your case; the whole *point* of this site is to help.

Answer (score 1):

A quick duckduckgo search provided :[Link To Guide With Items](http://darksoulswiki.wikispaces.com/Knight%27s+Honor+Achievement+Guide)

**Chaos Blade**

**Crystal Ring Shield**

**Darkmoon Bow**

**Dragonbone Fist**

**Dragonslayer Spear**

**Golem Axe**

**Great lord Greatsword**

**Greatshield of Artorias**

**Greatsword of Artorias**

**(True) Greatsword of Artorias**

**Lifehunt Scythe**

**Moonlight Butterfly Horn**

**Quelaag's Furysword**

**Smough's Hammer**

**Tin Darkmoon Catalyst**

--Weapons or Shields dropped by enemies--

**Black Knight Greataxe**

**Black knight Greatsword**

**Black Knight Halberd**

**Black Knight Shield**

**Black knight Sword**

**Channeler's Trident**

**Crest Shield**

**Crescent Axe**

**Demon's Spear**

**Giant's Halberd**

**Grant**

**Sanctus**

**Silver Knight Shield**

**Silver Knight Spear**

**Silver Knight Straight Sword**

**Stone Greatshield**

**Stone Greatsword**

--Weapons found as treasure--

**Astoria's Straight Sword**

**Blood Shield**

**Dragon Crest Shield**

**Dragon Tooth**

**Dragonslayer Greatbow**

**Effigy Shield**

**Havel's Greatshield**

**Velka's Rapier**

--Weapons or Shields acquired from covenants--

**Dark Hand**

**Gravelord Sword**

**Dragon Greatsword**

-- Weapons acquired from cutting off boss tails--

**Drake Sword**

**Dragonking Greataxe**

**Moonlight Greatsword**

**Priscilla's Dagger**

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue obtaining this trophy when you've used the Bottomless Box glitch to obtain all of the weapons. Downgrading one of your weapons and re-ascending it may help.

See here for more details: http://forums.demonssouls.info/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=15092